# How do I pass a user input variable inside subprocess_check_output?

Tags: python, shell, pyramid

I am a beginner trying to get a shell command from a user in Pyramid and pass it to    *subprocess.check_output["thisisthecommand"]*

The variable is stored in **myvar**. Eg:myvar="echo helloworld"
How to pass this variable inside my subprocess check_output?

I tried doing this    *subprocess.check_output[myvar]*
but it doesnt work. Pyramid throws the error 'AttributeError:NoneType object has no attribute'
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) (and the examples therein) you need to separate command and arguments in the list. e.g,

```
subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello'])
```

should work. There is a `shell` option which would allow you to write `subprocess.check_output('echo hello', shell=True)` but that is best left alone for security reasons.

If you use a variable `myvar` containing the command, you can use `shlex.split()` to produce a list suitable for passing to `check_output()`:

```
import shlex, subprocess
myvar = 'echo hello'
args = shlex.split(myvar)
output = subprocess.check_output(args)
>>> args
['echo', 'hello']
```

Incidentally, Python functions are invoked using using `()`, not `[]` - the latter used for indexing a sequence or accessing a dictionary by key.